# ORACLE SQL sort by column name with array

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle DB.

Now I have data table like this:

```
id | point_id | list_order
1  | 2,3,8    | 3,1,2
2  | 3,1      | 2,1
3  | 1,6      | 2,1
```

My question, how can I sort the data based on list_order ASC?
The result data should be:

```
id | point_id | list_order 
1  | 3        | 1
1  | 8        | 2
1  | 2        | 3
```

Comment: Is your point_id and list_order column text with "," separating the values are are they objects? Please explain this issue more clearly. In fact the solution you propose is nonsense, as the "id" column now has only a "1" in it.

Comment: @RobMascaro, the three rows with id "1" in the sample result were derived from the single row with id "1" in the source data. It's confusing because the result data should also include two rows for id "2" and two rows for id "3".

Comment: Did something not work for you.? Kindly let us know.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired from [`this solution`](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/184666/569455/#msg_569455)

```
with mydata(id,point_id,list_order)
as
(
  select 1,'2,3,8','3,1,2' from dual
  union all
  select 2,'3,1','2,1' from dual
  union all
  select 3,'1,6','2,1' from dual
)
SELECT  t1.id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(t1.point_id, '([^,])+', 1, t2.COLUMN_VALUE) point_id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(t1.list_order, '([^,])+', 1, t2.COLUMN_VALUE) list_order
FROM mydata t1 CROSS JOIN
            TABLE
            (
                CAST
                (
                    MULTISET
                    (
                        SELECT LEVEL
                        FROM DUAL 
                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(t1.point_id, '([^,])+')
                    )
                    AS SYS.odciNumberList
                )
            ) t2
ORDER BY ID,LIST_ORDER;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Oracle XML:

```
select  a.id,  
        trim( x.column_value.extract( 'e/text()' ) )  as list_order,
        trim( y.column_value.extract( 'e/text()' ) )  as point_id
 from  table  a
 join  table 
         ( xmlsequence
             ( xmltype
                 (   '<e><e>' 
                 ||  replace( a.list_order, ',', '</e><e>' )
                 ||  '</e></e>' ).extract ( 'e/e' ) 
             )
         )  x  
   on  ( 1=1 )
join  table 
         ( xmlsequence
             ( xmltype
                 (   '<e><e>' 
                 ||  replace( a.point_id, ',', '</e><e>' )
                 ||  '</e></e>' ).extract ( 'e/e' ) 
             )
         )  y  
   on  ( 1=1 )
```

and i find a really great link for your question. this man did a lot to try to solve the similar question. you can check it and try any 1 of them :)
http://steve-lyon.blogspot.hk/2013/07/aggregated-lists-decomposing-and.html